# If I have 580 REP, shouldn't I be 58% on my way to viewing vote counts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Just look at this:

[image: this screenshot].
I did the math, 580 = .58 of 1000.  I also refreshed the page, clicked on "view vote counts...." I haven't received any rep for a while...

Is it an update issue?

Comment: Its a rounding error, ignore it.

Comment: @random not sure the status is correct, see my comment to my answer. Did the team mention something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did the math, but used the wrong [base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix). 0.58 as a binary floating point number is slightly less than the decimal value, since it cannot be represented exactly:

[image]

Apparently they always round *down* the computed result to two decimal digits (i.e. to the next integer percentage), probably to prevent this page from showing an incorrect "100%" when you're at e.g. `19999/20000`.

Comment: I used some random Java applet (apparently they still exist) to get this value, so it might be off a bit at the less significant digits. But the overall reason is still this.

Comment: Now, of course the *real* solution (for presentation purposes) is to multiply your rep by `100` first, then divide by the required rep for the privilege, then round down to an integer. Display that value instead. Problem solved.

Comment: Doing some calcs on a few other accounts compared to the listed privileges they all show rounding down

Comment: @random The point here is that it rounds down *after* the floating point imprecision messes up things at the 8th decimal digit. 580/1000 shouldn't be 57%, unless you're doing it wrong (tm).

Comment: Doing it wrong is the only way to do maths